# Using twitter bootstrap wrong with blade?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-blade

Having a problem with making a container and its content mobile friendly and in the same time friendly on the desktop.

When I edit the css for .jumbotron to width: 1350px. It shows perfect in the desktop:

[image]

How it looks with smaller width of the browser, i have to scroll the center of the browser[image]:

When I edit the .jumbotron width to auto it shows perfect for mobile:

[image]

But not in desktop:

[image]

Blade code:

```
@extends('default')

@section('content')

<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
<br>
<h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Times målinger </h2>
<hr>
     @if(Session::has('message'))
        <p style="color: green;">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
       @endif
<div class="row formgroup">



    @if($errors->has())
        <ul>
            {{ $errors->first('badendeTime', '<li>:message</li>') }}
            {{ $errors->first('temp', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        </ul>
    @endif


     <div class="col-lg-6">
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/insertHT', 'method' => 'POST')) }}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ Form::label('pool_id', 'Basseng:') }}</td>
            <td>{{ Form::select('pool_id', $pools, Input::old('pool_id')) }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>{{ Form::label('Badende_per_Time', 'Badende per Time:') }}</td>
            <td>{{ Form::text('Badende_per_Time', Input::old('Badende_per_Time')) }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>{{ Form::label('Temperatur', 'Temperatur:') }}</td>
            <td>{{ Form::text('Temperatur', Input::old('Temperatur')) }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td>{{ Form::submit('Lagre', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {{ Form::close() }}


         </div>


    <div class="col-lg-6">

    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'bassengweb/insertHT', 'method' =>'POST')) }}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ Form::label('Luft_Temperatur', 'Luft Temperatur: ') }}</td>
            <td>{{ Form::text('Luft_Temperatur', Input::old('Luft_Temperatur')) }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td>{{ Form::submit('Lagre', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        {{ Form::close() }}

   </div>





    </div>
    </div>

@stop
```

Css:

```
.jumbotron {

    text-align: center; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    width: auto;


}

.formgroup {
  margin: auto auto;


}


h2  {

    text-align: center;
    margin-top: auto;
    }

.container {
    min-height: 530px;
     /* set border styling */
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;


    /* set border roundness */
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
     margin: 0 auto auto;
     width: auto;
    display: inline-block;

/*    height: 400px; */
 background-color: white;   

}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the form elements in a table? - This might not fix your issue: http://bootsnipp.com/forms?version=3 but it's better to use something like that, than to use tables to format the form.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be using tables to lay out your forms. The Bootstrap Docs show you how to do it: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Totally agree, tables in this context make me shiver in nostalgic dread

Comment: I tried it but the input box is large in width.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the table markup might be outdated, I doesn't affect the responsiveness. I find two primary problems with your code. First, it looks like you're missing one trailing `</div>`, so add to the before the `@stop`.

The second thing is, instead of `.jumbotron`, I think what you're looking for is `.container` to get that centered max width container.

If I'm wrong, what you essentially want to do is use `max-width: 1350px;`, and then set `width: 100%`. As you can imagine, what happens is if the screen goes below 1350px, it just stays at 100%. Then, if you want to center this box, use `margin: auto;`. I'm not sure if you accomplishing anything specific with `display: inline-block;`, you might want to change that to `block` as well.